# SQL Query with multiple between

Tags: sql, database, oracle, between

Select countries that fulfill one of the following conditions:
- Population is from 10 million to 20 million.
- Population is from 44 million to 55 million.

```
Please use the keywords BETWEEN.
```

This was question .I wrote the query but not getting the output. Please guide if you have got the mistake I am doing here

Here is my query:

```
select Id,Name,Capital,CurrencyCode,Population,EuropeUnionMember 
from Country 
where (population between 100000000 and 200000000) 
or (population between 440000000 and 550000000);
```

Comment: 100000000 is a 0 too many. 10 million is 10000000. Same goes for the other values. you could also use `(population between 10e6 and 20e6) or (population between 44e6 and 55e6)`, just so you are sure you are in millions.

Comment: Did my solution below answer your question? If not, please explain why. If so, please be courteous and accept/upvote my solution.

Comment: Yes your answer was right. I am not able to upvote because .I am new here and reputation must be 15 to upvote .Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNION command to achieve this task. I setup a simple demo for you below. Tailor it to fit your needs.

```
CREATE table MY_TABLE (country, population) AS 
SELECT 'France',150000000
FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'Spain',300000000
FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'England',444000000
FROM dual;

select country, population from my_table where population between 100000000 and 200000000
UNION
select country, population from my_table where population between 440000000 and 550000000;


COUNTRY    POPULATION
England    444000000
France    150000000
```